# Image to Video Conversion in Laravel Using FFMpeg

Tags: laravel, video, ffmpeg

i'm trying to convert a image into video with the use of FFMpeg in laravel. it generates the video but the the video duration is 0 second....

Here is my code...

```
        $filename = $_FILES['video']['name'];
        $tempname = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($tempname, storage_path('app/public/image2video/').$filename);

        FFMpeg::fromDisk('image2video')
            ->open($filename)
            ->addFilter('-loop', 3)
            // ->addFilter('-c:v', 'libx264')
            ->addFilter('-t', 3000)
            ->addFilter('-s', '1920x1080')
            // ->addFilter('-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p')
            ->export()
            ->toDisk('image2videoConverted')
            // ->dd('output.mp4');
            ->save('output.mp4');
```

here is my FFMpeg Command which is generating

```
   ffmpeg -y -i C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/textToSpeech2/storage/app/public/image2video/a.jpg -loop 3 -t 3000 -s 1920x1080 -threads 12 C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/textToSpeech2/storage/app/image2videoConverted/output.mp4
```

it converted the image into mp4 format and stored at my given location but the video length is 0 second.

Comment: Try different formats like png, gif to check output size.

Comment: the video is being generated but it's length is 0 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is my FFMpeg Command which is generating

```
ffmpeg -y -i C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/textToSpeech2/storage/app/public/image2video/a.jpg -loop 3 -t 3000 -s 1920x1080 -threads 12 C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/textToSpeech2/storage/app/image2videoConverted/output.mp4
```

> It converted the image into mp4 format and stored at my given location but the video length is 0 second.

You need to set the `-loop` part **first**, then it's followed by the input `-i`

A working command looks like this example:
*(for testing it sets duration `-t` to 60 seconds, later you can try encoding your 3000 seconds video)*.

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/textToSpeech2/storage/app/public/image2video/a.jpg -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 60 -threads 12 C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/textToSpeech2/storage/app/image2videoConverted/output.mp4
```

Comment: would you please tell me that without giving this folderwise path like: c:/xampp/.....
how can i give my use my storage path

Comment: cause when i give my storage path it fails to generate video\